# Disable only specific flat rate shipping method when free shipping is available in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I have two flat rates on my WooCommerce site and I want to disable one of them, when free shipping is enabled.  I have a function which is working for all flat rates only.

How do I check for an instance id on a shipping rate? Can anyone help me understand how to check for the instance id?

I Was trying to echo shipping data out to make sense of what values were available but no echo was showing on the front end either so a tip on why would be great.

Here is my code attempt:

```
function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {
    $new_rates = array();

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present.
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $new_rates ) ) {
        //Save local pickup if it's present.
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ('local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            }
            if ( 'flat_rate:20' === $rate->instance_id )
                $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate; 
            }
        return $new_rates;
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the shipping methods radio buttons on cart or in checkout you will see something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate20" value="flat_rate:20" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
```

So in `value="flat_rate:20"` *(which is the rate Id)*:

- **the method Id** is **`flat_rate`**,
- and **instance ID** is **`20`**.

**Note:** The code could be really simplified…

But as you don't provide the free shipping and other flat rate **rates IDs** *(or instances Ids)*, I Keep your code making some changes to it, this way:

```
function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {
    $new_rates = array();

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present.
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $new_rates ) ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            //Save local pickup if it's present.
            if ('local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            }
            if ( 20 == $rate->instance_id )
                $new_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            }
        }
        return $new_rates;
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
```

It should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for a quick answer!  Appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if free shipping is available based on its id. If it is available, it removes the shipping rate `flat_rate:20`.

> Replace `free_shipping:2` with your free shipping id.

```
// if free shipping is available, disable a specific shipping rate
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:2'] ) ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:20'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*