# Hide specific shipping methods based on cart subtotal in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I am trying to only show 1 shipping method when the cart subtotal is more than £50.

The website already has a lot of plugins, so I don't want to add anymore.

Any help is greatly welcomed.

Sophie

First - I have based the code on this from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571655/disable-only-specific-flat-rate-shipping-method-when-free-shipping-is-available):

```
`// if free shipping is available, disable a specific shipping rate
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:2'] ) ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:20'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}`
```

---

I adapted it to:

```
// if order is over £50, disable a specific shipping rate

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available', 10, 2 );

function hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available( $rates, $order_total ) {
        if ( $order_total > 50 ) {
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:9'] );
                unset( $rates['free_shipping:2'] );
            }
    return $rates;
}
```

---

This worked but now when the cart is below 50 it doesn't come back (I clear WC transients each time, have tried clearning page and browser caches too)

So I tried this:

```
`// if order is over £50, disable a specific shipping rate
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available( $rates, $order_total ) {
        if ( $order_total > 50 ) {
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:9'] );
                unset( $rates['free_shipping:2'] );
            }
             else {
                isset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
                isset( $rates['flat_rate:9'] );
                isset( $rates['free_shipping:2'] );
}
    return $rates;
}`
```

---

Another option I tried is:

```
``
// if order is over £50, disable a specific shipping rate
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( $order_total > 50 ) {
        if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:7'] ) ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:9'] );
        unset( $rates['free_shipping:2'] );
    }
    }
    return $rates;
}
``
```

I have read and tried other related threads too but they are either too different for me to adapt with my limited PHP knowledge, or they cause errors in functions.php

---

UPDATE

I've been doing some more testing, and it seems it works the first time, but when the cart is updated it doesn't change - so that is the part I guess that needs support on.

This code is a perfect example of that happening:

```
// if order is over £50, disable a specific shipping rate
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available', 10, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_rate_if_shipping_free_is_available( $rates, $order_total ) {
    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] ) && $order_total > 50) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Ignore the fact that the flat rates are different, my client has 2 sites and wants the same on both.

Comment: I've been doing some more testing, and it seems it works the first time, but when the cart is updated it doesn't change - so that is the part I guess that needs support on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code, as there is no `$order_total` function variable argument, as it's `$package` instead (the current shipping package).

To get the cart subtotal, you can use:

- Subtotal Including taxes: `WC()->cart->subtotal`,
- Subtotal Excluding taxes: `WC()->cart->get_subtotal()`.

So in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_rates_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_rates_conditionally( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal > 50 ) {
        if ( isset($rates['flat_rate:1']) ) {
            unset($rates['flat_rate:1']);
        }
        if ( isset($rates['flat_rate:9']) ) {
            unset($rates['flat_rate:9']);
        }
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:2']) ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:2']);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

It should work.

To refresh, shipping rates, once the code is added/saved, empty your cart.